# Random lines popping up with Freestile when Sketchy

Tags: freestyle

When I render a simple animation with Freestyle (all default settings, except sketchy at 3 and the Bezier modifier at 50) I get this result on some frames:

[image: Annoying lines]

There are some lines appearing out of nowhere. The model has a simple diffuse material (not rendered in passes). How can I solve this without losing the sketchy style?

Here is a succesful image:
[image: Looking Nice]

And the blend file:

http://pasteall.org/blend/40571

Frames 21 and 24 illustrate the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your scene setup. Could you show a bit more? How many objects are there? Does the "random line" appear also in render from other camera's points of view (same frame)?

Comment: Please show a successful image and a failed image minimum.

Comment: Edited the question, including the blend file and another screenshot

Answer (score 4):

Play with the error settings for the bezier curve modifier:

Original:

[image]

Smaller value:

[image]

Comment: Had the same issue. Tried your solution and no value worked. But hey, I removed the bezier and it saved my life.